# Galois theory of endomorphism rings of irreducible representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations, central-simple-algebras

Let $k$ be a field which I don't suppose to be algebraically closed. Then, the endomorphism ring of any irreducible representation of a finite group over $k$ is a division ring.

What is known about these division rings? When are they fields? When they are, are these fields Galois over $k$? At least, normal? When not, are the centers of the division rings Galois over $k$? What do we know about these centers?

If $k$ is a perfect field, do the irreducible representations themselves split into *distinct* irreducible representations over the algebraic closure of $k$, or can some be equal?

Sorry for this many questions that are probably well-known, but I can't find an introductory text on representation theory which takes non-algebraically closed fields seriously.

Comment: Touché. I was thinking about groups.

Comment: See Part II of Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups* for a nice introduction to representation theory over a nonalgebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.  Some keywords: Schur indices, Schur subgroup.  M. Isaacs's book on representation theory covers these topics in somewhat greater depth.  

Comment: In particular, the example of the quaternion group of order $8$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is one to keep in mind.  This is the smallest group order for which $\mathbb{Q}[G]$ has a factor which is a noncommutative division algebra.  When this occurs, the corresponding irreducible reprsentation "ramifies", i.e., decomposes into multiple copies of the same geometrically irreducible representation.

Comment: Thanks! Good point about the quaternions. If it wouldn't ramify, then the division ring would have to be geometrically a product of $\overline k$'s and thus couldn't be noncommutative.

Comment: To add to Pete's comments, a reference for the determination of the Schur subgroup, i.e., the set of division algebras that appear, is Yamada: The Schur subgroup of the Brauer group, SLN 397.

Comment: Every irreducible representation of a finite group in characteristic
zero is realizable over a cyclotomic field (see Lang's
*Algebra*). So the centre of any division ring that arises as the
endomorphism ring of an irrep over a characteristic zero field
$k$ will be an abelian extension of $k$. But over $\mathbb{Q}$
or $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the only examples of noncommutative endomorphism
rings of irreps I've seen have been quaternionic. Are there
examples where the degree of the division ring over its centre
is greater than $4$?

Comment: Robin: yes, they can be arbitrarily large. Isaacs's Character Theory gives some examples.  Galois groups are groups, so it is not very hard to turn a standard crossed product into part of a group ring.  I've posted some examples on AoPS in the past, maybe here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning

> are the centers of the division rings Galois over $k$

A finite dim'l $k$-algebra $A$ is 
*split* provided $\operatorname{End}_A(S) = k$
for every simple $A$-module $S$.

[This terminology is consistent with that used
in other contexts -- $A$ is split
just in case the reductive quotient of the "unit group" $A^\times$ is a split reductive algebraic group over $k$.]

Suppose that $k$ is perfect and that $A_\ell = A \otimes_k \ell$ is a split $\ell$-algebra for a finite, separable extension $\ell \supset k$. Then we have the following:

> $(*)$ If $S$ is a simple $A$-module, the center $Z$ of the division $k$-algebra $\operatorname{End}_A(S)$ is a subfield of $\ell$.

To see this, I claim first that $\operatorname{End}_A(S) \otimes_k \ell$ is a split semisimple
$\ell$-algebra. Indeed, since $k \subset \ell$ is separable, the $A_\ell$-module $S \otimes_k \ell = S_\ell$ is semisimple, say $S_\ell = \bigoplus_i S_i$ as $A_\ell$-module, where $S_i$ is the $T_i$-isotypic
component of $S_\ell$ and where $T_i$ are distinct simple $A_\ell$-modules. Since
by assumption $\operatorname{End}_{A_\ell}(T_i) = \ell$, we see
that $$\operatorname{End}_A(S) \otimes_k \ell \simeq \operatorname{End}_{A_\ell}(S_\ell) = \prod_i \operatorname{End}_{A_\ell}(S_i)$$
is a product of full matrix algebras over $\ell$. Now observe that the center of a split semisimple $\ell$-algebra
is a  a split commutative etale $\ell$-algbra $\ell \times \cdots \times \ell$. Assertion $(*)$
now follows.

Apply this to $A = kG$ for a finite group $G$. By Torsten's comment (following Emerton's answer) we may suppose $k$ to be perfect. 
Then $A \otimes_k \ell$ is split
for an *Abelian* extension $\ell$ of $k$ -- a suitable $\ell$ can be obtained by adjoining to $k$ enough roots of unity. It follows that $Z$ is always Galois over $k$ (for $A = kG$).

Comment: Sounds interesting. Typo: End_k (S) = k should be End_A (S) = k. Also, I suppose A (X)_k l should be split as l-algebra, not as k-algebra?

Comment: I don't see how you conclude that $\left(\mathrm{End}_AS\right)\otimes_k\ell$ is a split semisimple $\ell$-algebra, but I'll come back to this later when I have more time to seriously think about it (have to prepare talk about something quite different).

Comment: Thanks for typo-spotting. Perhaps the edited version is clearer
re: split semisimplicity?

Comment: I have not forgotten your answer, but I'm first going to read some semisimple theory before I go through it. At the moment I know the properties of semisimple algebras only over algebraically closed fields, which is definitely not enough.

Comment: I think the treatment of semisimple algebras given by Curtis and Reiner [Methods of representation theory. Vol. I. 
With applications to finite groups and orders] takes non-alg closed fields seriously in this context. As does Lang's Algebra, I'm sure. (Well, this is all by memory -- my copies of both of those books are at my office...)

Comment: Sorry for half a year of procrastination - I have now finally read your post until the end. It looks very good, thanks. I still don't understand two things, though. First, why is the $A_{\ell}$-module $S\otimes_k \ell$ semisimple? Second, in the very last absatz of your post, why can a suitable $\ell$ be obtained by adjoining to $k$ enough roots of unity? I know that this follows from Artin's theorem in the case when $\mathrm{char} k=0$, but this seems very indirect to me and I don't see how to extend it to all perfect $k$. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: For your first question:  if $A$ is a $k$-algebra, an $A$-module $S$ is semisimple if and only if the image $B$ of $A$ in $End_k(S)$ is a semisimple algebra. Now the image of $A_\ell$ in $End_\ell(S\otimes_k \ell)$ is evidently $B_\ell$. Now use that if $k \subset \ell$ is separable, $B$ semisimple $\implies B_\ell$ semisimple.

Comment: For your second question, see [Curtis & Reiner, Methods of Representation Theory Volume 1, Theorem 17.1] (p. 418 in my paperback copy...)

Comment: Thank you! I see my second question was trivial anyway. Since there are only finitely many simple $kG$-modules over the algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$, there is a finite extension $m$ of the prime field of $k$ such that all of these simple modules are defined over $m$. Thus, the $m$-algebra $mG$ splits. Since $m$ is a finite field (because the prime field of $k$ is finite, and $m$ is a finite extension of $k$), all elements of $m$ are roots of unity (except of zero). Now, if $\ell$ denotes the compositum of $m$ and $k$ over the prime field of $k$, then $\ell$ is an extension of ...

Comment: ... $k$ obtained by adjoining roots of unity, and $\ell G$ splits over $\ell$. This answers my second question. 

Comment: As for the first one, you've got a nice trick of reducing the semisimplicity of a module to that of an algebra!

Answer (score 9):

Pete's reference and other remarks in his comments are absolutely the right place to look/thing to think about.  Let me make a slightly more elaborate remark, which may be helpful.

A key fact which helps one think about this sort of question is the following: if 
$V$ is a rep. of $G$ over $k$, and $l$ is a finite extension of $k$, 
then $End_{l[G]}(l\otimes_k V) = l\otimes_k End_{k[G]}(V).$  (This is easily checked.)

At least if $k$ is perfect, then when $V$ is irreducible over $k$ the base-change
$l\otimes_k V$ will be semisimple over $l$ (i.e. a direct sum of irreds.).
Given this, one can determine its structure (is it a sum of distinct irreds., say, or does it contain two copies of the same irrep.?) by looking at $End_{l[G]}(l\otimes_k V)$, which
as I already noted we can compute as $l\otimes_k End_{k[G]}(V)$.

Let's suppose that $l = \bar{k}$, since that's probably the case of greatest interest.
Then if $W$ is a direct sum of mutually non-isomorphic irreps., then $End_{\bar{k}[G]}(W)$
is a product of copies of $\bar{k}$, as many as there are summands of $W$.
(If $W = \oplus_i W_i,$ then we get one copy of $\bar{k}$ for each $W_i$, since $End_{\bar{k}[G]}(W) = \bar{k}$, but there are no maps between the different $W_i$,
since they are non-isomorphic by assumption.)   On the other hand, if say $W$ were 
a direct sum $W = W_1\oplus W_2,$ then $End_{\bar{k}[G]}(W) = M_2(\bar{k})$
(since $Hom_{\bar{k}[G]}(W_i,W_j) = \bar{k}$ for any choice of $i$ and $j$).

Now using our formula $End_{\bar{k}[G]}(\bar{k}\otimes_k V) = \bar{k}\otimes_k End_{k[G]}(V),$ we see that $\bar{k}[G]\otimes_k V$ is a direct sum of *distinct*
irreps. if and only if $End_{k[G]}(V)$ is a field (since it is precisely this case which
gives a product of copies of $\bar{k}$ when we tensor up with $\bar{k}$), while
$\bar{k}\otimes_k V$ will contain *multiple copies* of some irrep. if and only 
if $End_{k[G]}(V)$ is a non-commutative division ring, since then extending scalars to
$\bar{k}$ will give a non-trivial matrix ring over $\bar{k}$. (This explains Pete's remark about the quaternion group in his comment above.)
More precisely, we see that if $End_{k[G]}(V)$ is a division ring of dimension $n^2$
over its centre, which has say degree $d$ over $k$, then
$\bar{k}\otimes_k V$ will be a product of $n$ copies each of $d$ distinct irreps. over $\bar{k}$.

Comment: Hey, I was about to write that answer!

Comment: The case of non-perfect k is really no problem. The group ring is
defined over the prime field $\mathbb Z/p$ and it modulo its radical
is a product of matrix rings (by Wedderburn's theorem) with centers
that are separable extensions. This implies that the same thing is
true for any field of positive characteristic

Comment: Dear Torsten,

Thanks for this helpful remark.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post, Emerton, but I already saw the argument when Pete mentioned the quaternion group.

Comment: To put Emerton's concern about imperfectness in perspective, if $(V,\rho)$ is a finite-dimensional semisimple linear representation of a general group $G$ (perhaps infinite), all over a field $k$, when $G$ is infinite semisimplicity can be lost after a ground field extension when $k$ is imperfect. (Related fact: for a finite-dim. simple $k$-algebra $A$, $k' \otimes_k A$ can be non-ss if $k'/k$ is inseparable and $A$ has center inseparable over $k$.) For example, if $k' = k(a^{1/p})$ with $p = {\rm{char}}(k) > 0$ and $a \in k$ not a $p$-power, take $V = k'$ and $G = \mathbf{Z}$ with $1.v = av$.